# How to simulate multiple different HTTP responses using Go's httptest?

Tags: go, testing, go-testing

I have created some Go functions that make HTTP GET calls to services that are out there on the internet and parse the results.

I am now working on writing test-cases for these functions.
In my test cases, I'm using the go package `httptest` to simulate calls to these external services. Below is my code. Error checking is purposefully removed for brevity. Here is the [go-playground](https://play.golang.org/p/upTh4uwuHTB).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func handlerResponse() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"A":"B"}`))
    })
}

func buildMyRequest(ctx context.Context, url string) *http.Request {
    request, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", url, nil)
    return request
}

func myPrint(response *http.Response) {
    b := make([]byte, 60000)
    for {
        _, err := response.Body.Read(b)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func main() {
    srv := httptest.NewServer(handlerResponse())            
    client := http.Client{}

    myResponse1, _ := client.Do(buildMyRequest(context.Background(), srv.URL))
    fmt.Println("myResponse1:")
    myPrint(myResponse1)
    
    myResponse2, _ := client.Do(buildMyRequest(context.Background(), srv.URL))
    fmt.Println("myResponse2:")
    myPrint(myResponse2)

}
```

This is the output it produces:

```
myResponse1:
{"A":"B"}
myResponse2:
{"A":"B"}
```

As you can see, I have created some dummy HTTP response data `{"A":"B"}` and when you send an HTTP request to `srv.URL`, it actually hits an ephemeral HTTP server which responds with the dummy data. Cool!

When you send the second HTTP request to `srv.URL`, it again responds with the same dummy data. But this is where my problem arises. I want the ephemeral HTTP server to return some different data the second time `{"C":"D"}` and third time `{"E":"F"}` it receives a request.

How can I change the first line of the `main()` function so that the server responds with my desired data on subsequent HTTP calls?

Comment: Either: The handler you use in the httptest.Server has to implement this, or: Use different httptest.Servers with different handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a hack like follows ( playground : [here](https://play.golang.org/p/OC5Q_JODsbC))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "sync"
)


type responseWriter struct{
   resp map[int]string
   count int
   lock *sync.Mutex
}

func NewResponseWriter()*responseWriter{
   r := new(responseWriter)
   r.lock = new(sync.Mutex)
   r.resp = map[int]string{
    0: `{"E":"F"}`,
    1: `{"A":"B"}`,
    2: `{"C":"D"}`,
   }
   r.count = 0
   return r
}

func (r *responseWriter)GetResp()string{
   r.lock.Lock()
   defer r.lock.Unlock()
   r.count ++
   return r.resp[r.count%3]
}


func handlerResponse(rr *responseWriter) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(rr.GetResp()))
    })
}

func buildMyRequest(ctx context.Context, url string) *http.Request {
    request, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", url, nil)
    return request
}


func myPrint(response *http.Response) {
    b := make([]byte, 60000)
    for {
        _, err := response.Body.Read(b)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func main() {
        rr := NewResponseWriter()

    srv := httptest.NewServer(handlerResponse(rr))  
    client := http.Client{}

    myResponse1, err := client.Do(buildMyRequest(context.Background(), srv.URL))
    if err != nil{
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
    }
    
    defer myResponse1.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("myResponse1:")
    myPrint(myResponse1)
    
    myResponse2, err := client.Do(buildMyRequest(context.Background(), srv.URL))
    if err != nil{
       fmt.Println(err)
       return
    }
    
    defer myResponse2.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("myResponse2:")
    myPrint(myResponse2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! However I simplified it even further than what you have shown. I changed `resp` from a `map[int]string` into a `[]string`. And I removed the mutex. It was not needed.

Comment: great. The mutex is useful to avoid data races if you are running table driven tests in concurrently.